# Setting different sub-routes in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two `routes` to route to one `controller` called `storyboard`.

One with $routeParams and one without it.

```
     $routeProvider.when('/storyboard/:cureId',
    {
        templateUrl:    '/partials/storyboard.html',
        controller: 'Storyboard',
        access: access.parent,
        area:     'storyboard'
    });    

$routeProvider.when('/storyboard/addTarget',
    {
        templateUrl:'/partials/storyboard_new_target.html',
        controller: 'Storyboard',
        access: access.supervisor,
        area:     'storyboard'
    });   

$routeProvider.when('/storyboard/addSession',
    {
        templateUrl:'/partials/storyboard_new_session.html',
        controller: 'Storyboard',
        access: access.parent,
        area:     'storyboard'
    });     


$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo:'/404'});
```

But when i call `/storyboard/addSession` Angular always redirects me to `/storyboard/addSession` , and get `addSession` with $routeParams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngRoute` processes route based on order of registration. So `/storyboard/addSession` should match the first route (i.e. `/storyboard/:cureId`). I suppose you want it to match the third route in the example. Just update the order so that the parameterized route is registered last.

```
$routeProvider.when('/storyboard/addTarget',
{
    templateUrl:'/partials/storyboard_new_target.html',
    controller: 'Storyboard',
    access: access.supervisor,
    area:     'storyboard'
});   
$routeProvider.when('/storyboard/addSession',
{
    templateUrl:'/partials/storyboard_new_session.html',
    controller: 'Storyboard',
    access: access.parent,
    area:     'storyboard'
});     
$routeProvider.when('/storyboard/:cureId',
{
    templateUrl:    '/partials/storyboard.html',
    controller: 'Storyboard',
    access: access.parent,
    area:     'storyboard'
});
```

Comment: can you still use the ```<div ng-view></div>``` for sub routes?